# concat code with macro in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Here's the thing:

Let's say I have two function defined in C:

```
test_1() {};
test_2() {};
```

I would like to have a macro (e.g. NUM_TEST) that will refer to test number. Best way is to show it in code:

```
#define NUM_TEST 1

test_1() {};
test_2() {};

int main() {
    test_ ## NUM_TEST ## ()
}
```

I would appreciate, if someone would help, to find a solution, how to concat name of function with macro.

**EDIT:**

To make it more clear. I would like to just by changing of "macro NUM_TEST" change invoked function between test_1() and test_2().

Yes I know there are more easier ways to do that, but this is just an example to more general problem: How to concat macro with text in C without adding new lines or new macro functions.

**EDIT 2:**

Obviously I was now clear enough. Let's say I wrote a program. It has two (or more) run types. I have one macro called NUM_TEST. By setting mentioned macro to 1 or 2 a want to choose run type between test_1() or test_2()

Thank you!

Comment: Why do people like macros? Scared of compilers? They usually end in tears. Only good for a few things

Comment: Are you trying to specify which function to run based on a pre-processor directive?  Why not just use a switch? You might also consider using an #ifdef.

Comment: Please read your question and  make it reasonable

Comment: `test_ ## NUM_TEST ## ()` needs to go inside another macro defintion.

Comment: Please decide on a language.  Is it C or C++?  The macro preprocessor is the same but the solution you'd actually want to use is probably different.  Your function definitions, by the way, are invalid in either language.

Comment: It is C. @EdHeal macros can be great thing if you do power computing (which is my case), to exclude lot of if and switch statements. It requires additional compilation before you want to use it, but it can save lot of time.

Comment: @Addman - They are not. They lack type safety. They make code harder to read. They make code not maintainable. They make debugging more difficult. It is not power computing. (PS: As a "power" programmer why tag this as C++?)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Then the whole thing get incomprehensible.

Comment: @EdHeal Well, I just addressed the technical issue. If I had thought this would be a _good answer_, then I won't have posted it as a comment :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I find it amusing that some people have this love affair with macros. My experience is that some people tend to overuse them

Comment: @EdHeal I'm strongly discouraging use of macros, and I certainly not have a love affair with them. Though the question is about a simple technical issue with the CPP preprocessor.

Comment: @EdHeal True, I agree, macros can make code pretty unreadable. But sometimes they can help safe time, especially when code lengths are no more than few hundreds of lines. And I taget it as C++ because it is not C or C++ issue, but C preprocessor issue, which are common to both (at least I think so).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I did not say that you did have a love affair with them. I think that you have the same mind set as myself. I find some questions on this web site that people are doing stupid things with macros.

Comment: @Addman - Do the (I assume you meant) save time? Try reading/review the code. Try debugging the code. Try coming back in a year and debug/amend the code. Perhaps those few keystrokes that took an extra minute would have been better.

Comment: @EdHeal As I said: I agree with you. Using macros is dangerious. In this case we are in angreement. Countless times I was cursing my self that I was not more carefull in writing my code. I am trying to say that sometimes it is not such dum thing to use macros. Obviously we have different opinion in this particular case.

Comment: Just write a switch statement. Or put the function pointers into an array.

Comment: Yes that is one of more possibilities. This is just an example that was bothering me for a while (few years). I always solved it otherwise, even with function pointer. (actually I am often blamed for overusage of pointers, which is not great either)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72919/discussion-between-addman-and-ed-heal).

Comment: Can you give a little more context on this problem?  Are you using the macro to check some system settings and determining the test to run based on the result?  What is determining which test to execute?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST(NUM) test_ ## NUM ()

test_1() { printf ("Hello "); }
test_2() { printf ("World!\n"); }


int main (void)
{
  TEST(1);
  TEST(2);
  // Prints "Hello World!\n"

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems a rather silly way of coding (and good luck with debugging)

Comment: Actually I wanted to do opposite, defining one macro NUM which is 1 or 2, I want to execute function test_1() or test_2().

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a Macro that determines this, it is better to just pass command line argument to it which represents the test number.  Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  
{
   switch(argv[1])
   {
       case "1"  :
           Test_1();
           break; 
       case "2"  :
           Test_2();
           break; 
       default : 
           printf("Test ID not found");
    }
}
```

If you are, however, just looking to alias a name, you can have your functions Test_1, Test_2, etc. Then just have a generic TESTTORUN wherever you want the selected test to run.  On compilation have the preprocessor replace it with the function name you want:

```
#define TESTTORUN Test_1  //Or Test_2 or whatever
```

This will cause the compiler to replace TESTTORUN everywhere in the program with Test_1.

Comment: This is not a help. Of course I can use switch statement or use whole function name as a macro. But is not my question. I am asking if it is possible to merge macro value with function name somewhere in code. Besides your "switch" code is strange. I should decide between test number by number of arguments? So if I want to use Test_15 I should provide 14 arbitrary words? There is any conversion between arguments (char*) to test number (int).

Comment: You are right, I wasn't paying enough attention when I wrote my answer and I missed that error on the switch statement, I have corrected it.  A reason for doing this would go a long way towards getting better answers.  If you simply want to use a macro to determine the test to run or change the test to run at run time, I have given solutions to both of these.  Why would you want to change the name of a function based on a macro?  What is your goal?  You seem to not like arbitrary words being used so is it some optimization problem, cause you didn't mention that in the question.